# Async Callback threw an exception

Tags: c#, autofac, nservicebus

I am getting the following error when trying to NServiceBus with autofac DI:

InvalidOperationException: The IAsyncResult implementation 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel]' tried to complete a single operation multiple times. This could be caused by an incorrect application of IAsyncResult implementation or other extensibility code, such as an IAsyncResult that returns incorrect CompletedSynchronously values, or invokes the AsyncCallback multiple times.

WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            try
            {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
                builder.RegisterType<MessageHandler>().As<IMessageHandler>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

                var container = builder.Build();

                var bus = CreateBusInstance(container);
                builder.RegisterInstance(bus).As<IBus>().SingleInstance();
                var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
                config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static IBus CreateBusInstance(ILifetimeScope container)
        {
            var configuration = new BusConfiguration();
            configuration.EndpointName("ServiceBusName");
            configuration.DisableFeature<SecondLevelRetries>();
            configuration.DisableFeature<Sagas>();
            configuration.DisableFeature<TimeoutManager>();
            configuration.ScaleOut().UseSingleBrokerQueue();
            configuration.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence>();
            configuration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>().ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ServiceBus"].ToString());
            configuration.UseSerialization<XmlSerializer>();
            configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(cust => cust.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));
            return Bus.Create(configuration).Start();
        }
    }
```

MessageHandler:

```
using nservciebus.Models;
using NServiceBus;

namespace nservciebus.ServiceBusHandler
{
    public class MessageHandler : IMessageHandler
    {
        private readonly IBus _bus;

        public MessageHandler(IBus bus)
        {
            _bus = bus;
        }

        public void Handle(ServiceBusMessage message)
        {
            _bus.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Nuget package in use:
- Autofac: 3.5.2
- Autofac.Owin: 4.0
- Autofac.WebApi2: 4.0
- Autofac.WebApi2.Owin: 4.0
- NServiceBus: 5.2.14
- NServiceBus.Autofac: 5.0
- NServiceBus.Azure.transports.WindowsAzureServiceBus: 6.4
- NServiceBus.Azure: 6.2.3
- WindowsAzure.Storage: 4.3
- WindowsAzure.ServiceBus: 2.8.2

AnyIdeas on what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

Thanks